# bash: How to use sed's hold and pattern space to dynamically swap list content?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable $MYVAR with this content:

```
Line 5
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

What I want to acomplish is to change the contents of the variable like so:

```
(1st iteration)             (2nd iteration)             (3rd iteration)

 Line 5                      Line 5                      Line 5
 Line 4                      Line 4                      Line 3
 Line 3                      Line 2                      Line 2
 Line 1                      Line 1                      Line 1
 Line 2                      Line 3                      Line 4
```

-> exchange the last line of the variable with the nth+1 line counting from the end of the variable (the number of lines can change).

What I got so far:

```
counter=1
function change_selection {
  src=$( echo "$MYVAR" | wc -l )
  dest=$((src-$counter))
  MYVAR=$( echo "$MYVAR" | sed -ne "${src}BIGPROBLEM${dest}" )
  $((counter++))
}
```

Can you help me to solve the "BIGPROBLEM" part? ;) I think the sed hold and pattern space commands can help me there, but I just cannot get my head around it..

Comment: Any time you use the words "hold space" and/or "pattern space" you are using the wrong tool as the associated sed language constructs to support anything other than `s/old/new` literally became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `sed` to modify a multi-line string, and use an array instead.

```
array=(
  "Line 5"
  "Line 4"
  "Line 3"
  "Line 2"
  "Line 1"
)

counter=1

change_selection () {
    src=$((${#array[@]} - 1 ))
    dest=$((src - counter))
    tmp="${array[dest]}"
    array[dest]=${array[-1]}
    array[-1]=$tmp
    ((counter++))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed '2{h;d;};$G;' <<< "$MYVAR"
```

- `2{h;d}`: line 2 is stored in the hold space and deleted from pattern space
- `$G`: hold space content is added to the pattern space at the end of the variable